# Javascript - how to add emoji on top of video

Tags: javascript, cordova, video-streaming, html5-video, phonegap-plugins

i am using Cordova to do my mobile apps.

Would like to check how to add a layer on top of video to display the emoji. It is like facebook, have a layer to display the thumbs up, angryface during the playing of the video.

Comment: Just make a div with your emoji and make the position with css - that's it.

Comment: can you show some example div and css code ?